# Is it possible to make a background image repeat vertically. But, also horizontally only to the right side using CSS?

Tags: css, image, background

So basically we have an background image (red) and we want it to repeat as the following with CSS:

[alt text http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/4417/repeat.png](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/4417/repeat.png)

*So I don't want it to repeat to the upper and left side.*

(sorry I suck at ASCII Art)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but isn't that the default? `background-repeat` is set to `repeat` unless you change it, which repeats both ways

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to repeat only one row on the top and one row on the left? If that's the case you'll need to break the background into two elements.

Comment: You might benefit from using an image to describe what you want to do. I'm at least as confused by your question as @Michael Mrozek and @ghoppe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want only to repeat one row and one column of the image. This can be accomplished with [CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image).

Currently only WebKit-based and KHTML (Konqueror) browsers support this.

```
 body {
      background: url(myimage.png) top left repeat-x, 
                  url(myimage.png) top left repeat-y;
 }
```

That said, although I'm quite confused about what you really want, I think you should be using multiple `div` elements arranged by css positioning the way you want and have different backgrounds on each.

Edit: Seeing your new photo it seems my sample is backwards to what you want. Anyway, my advice stands. Why aren't you using two `div` elements or a `margin-left` to move your desired background element over? Rethink the structure of your document.

Comment: Oh thanks God, someone got it. I have to work on my English grammar.

Comment: @janoChen, I'm simply glad that you were willing to persist and try to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just set the `background-repeat` property to `repeat`. I'm pretty sure this is the default value.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-repeat).

Comment: But isn't going to repeat to the left and upper side too?

Comment: Yes, but by default the background image "starts" from the top-left corner of the element in question, so there's no more "left" and "up" to go. Could you be a little more specific about what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: In fact, it would be great if we could see the actual HTML structure of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want images in positions 1, 2, 3, 4, and 7 (and so on), right?

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

if so, no such CSS rule exists; you'll have to alter your markup to place elements where you want the backgrounds.  `z-index`  and `position:relative` will be useful to you there.

Answer (score 1):

No, "repeat" directions go both ways: if you repeat to the right, it will repeat to the left as well. Same with up and down. Your best bet is to wrap the background in a div of the proper size, but it depends on your exact requirements.